# Display collision space in rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, collision

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm experimenting with arm_navigation with kuka youbot.

I am using move_arm to plan and execute trajectories from my code, now I'd like to add obstacles (both in the form of primitive objects and point clouds) to the planning environment.

I followed this tutorial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/motion_planning_environment/Tutorials/Adding%20known%20objects%20to%20the%20collision%20environment
(I just modified the code in order to use arm_navigation_msgs types)

When I run the code, I correctly get:

[ INFO] [1358768215.370171520]: Added 1 object to namespace pole in collision space

My question is: how can I view the collision environment in rviz? I just want to view which obstacles where added along with the model of the robot.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52902/display-collision-space-in-rviz/) by [Kilin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3758/kilin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2013-01-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kilin](https://answers.ros.org/users/3758/kilin/) on 2013-01-21**:
Thank you for your reply. Well, I don't see neither a planning_scene_markers topic, nor a PlanningScene display type when I click "add" in rviz..

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-01-21**:
It should be a Marker display/topic. It shows up in our system, but maybe it's something custom that is launched somewhere and not a feature of the environment_server itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add a PlanningScene Marker display at /planning_scene_markers.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2019-07-31**:
It doesn't show up...